# Split string and just get number in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string like `"GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n"` I just want get the number something like this `['7018', '6453', '12654']`, I tries regular expression but I can't split string to get just number here is my code:

Sample 1:

```
splitter = re.compile(r'\D');
match1 = splitter.split("GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n")

my output is: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '7018', '6453', '12654', '']
```

Sample 2:

```
splitter = re.compile(r'\W');
match1 = splitter.split("GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n")

my output is: ['GoTo', '', '7018', '6453', '12654', '']
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If all your numbers are positive integers, you can do that without regular expressions by using the [isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method:

```
>>> text = "GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n"
>>> [token for token in text.split() if token.isdigit()]
['7018', '6453', '12654']
```

Comment: +1 for non-re. One could easily throw `int(item)` in there as well, if this was needed later on.

Comment: Did some `timeit`... If split+isdigit is the base value (it is the fastest), compiled re.findall is 1.5 times slower and uncompliled re.findall 2.5.

Comment: This works only if the separator is pure whitespace (for example even "1, 2, 3" would break it)

Comment: @6502, true, but you can specify the separator in the first argument to `split()` if it's not pure whitespace.

Comment: It's all about how you read the problem. By "I've a string like" I supposed it wasn't wise to assume a too strict meaning for "like" so in my opinion the separators are everything but digits ("I just want to get the number") and split can't do it... this makes the problem a job for re. Apparently however not using re is a plus for reasons that I don't understand... and now we got anoter wannabe python programmer that will write bad brittle code instead of learning how to use a regexp.

Comment: @6502, there's an [old saying](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) that goes: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.` Okay, seriously, it's just a matter of performance versus requirements, I don't have anything against regexes *per se* :)

Comment: While I somewhat agree with such a saying for XML, I personally never had such a feeling about regexp despite having used them a lot (including writing a regexp engine myself). The speed point is quite weak, and was even shown by that re-antiboy AFTER awarding a point for not using regexp. I see someone (the original poster) that gave up with the correct solution (re) for silly reasons (he was just using split instead of findall) and probably will give up studying regexps thanks to stack overflow. And I feel a bit sad about it...

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', 'GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n')
['7018', '6453', '12654']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[0-9]+", "GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n")
['7018', '6453', '12654']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow your current method in sample 1 along with this code:

```
filter (lambda a: a != '', match1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
splitter = re.compile(r'\d+')
match1 = splitter.findall("GoTo: 7018 6453 12654\n")
print match1
```